# Nodejs sometimes not passing arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I built a website and it includes a registration page where I send an email using SendGrid's APi,
but sometimes it just doesn't work as expected

Here's the code calling the sendgrid function

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
   {name, email} = req.body 
   const token = makeString(10)

   newUser
        .save()
        .then(user => {
             req.flash(
                  'success_msg',
                  `You'll get your token in your email`
             );

             EmailService.sendEmail(name, email, token);
             res.redirect('/users/login');
         })

        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here's the function generating the token

```
const makeString = (length) => {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = '0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
 }
```

And here's the sendgrid function

```
const sendEmail = (name, email, token) => {
    sgMail.send({
        to : email,
        from :'example@example.com',
        subject : `example`,
        text : `Name    : ${name}\n Email   : ${email}\n Your login token : ${token}\n .`
    })
}
```

Sommetimes, the token doesn't show up in the email. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: When you call `EmailService.sendEmail(name, email, nrp, token);`, where does the `token` come from in that code? You don't show it.  We need more code context.  Can we see the whole request handler that contains the `sendEmail()`?

Comment: I added the string generator for the token here, and the request handler.

Comment: When you say sometimes the token doesn't show up in the email, what exactly is in the email?  Does the email arrive?  Can you show exactly what the text in the email is when it doesn't work properly?  Are the `${name}` and `${email}` shown properly in the email text?

Comment: Yes it's just the token that doesn't show up

Comment: It doesn't appear that there's anything in the code you show that would cause just the `token` to randomly not show up so there must  be something else going on in code you don't show us or a bug in `sgMail.send()`.  On a separate topic, this `{name, email} = req.body ` looks like it should be `const {name, email} = req.body;`.